# How can I in MIPS(MARS) assembly language check if the result of a multiplication between matrixes is correct?

Tags: arrays, mips

The fact is that I had to do a program in assembler MIPS consisting of given a 2x2 matrix and a vector of two elements multiply each other. The fact is that I think the code works but I do not know if I'm saving the results well or if it works badly, and I do not know how to prove it either. If someone could look at the code and tell me how it would be very grateful. Thank you very much in advance. I attach the code:

```
.text
.globl begin

begin:  
        la $t0, matrix      
        la $t1, matrix_out  
        la $t2, array
        li $t3, 0       
        li $t4, 0       

loop:
        lw $t5, ($t0)
        lw $t6, ($t2)
        mul $t7, $t6,$t5

        add $t0, $t0, 4     
        add $t2, $t2, 4     
        add $t8, $t8, $t7
        sw $t8, ($t1)
        add $t1, $t1, 4 
        add $t3, $t3, 1

        bne $t3, 2, loop
        add $t8, $0, $0 
        add $t2,$t2,-8
        add $t3, $zero, $zero   
        add $t4, $t4, 1     
        bne $t4, 2, loop

        li $v0, 10
        syscall 

 .data  

matrix:     .word 1,2,3,4  
matrix_out: .space 8 
array:      .word 5,6
```

Comment: Do you not know what the result the program should produce, or do you not know how to verify it?

Comment: @ScottHunter  I don't know how to verify it In the compiler, which in this case is the MARS 4.5. When I look at the records in which I keep the result, it seems to do the right thing, but i don't know how to check this